# How can I format a price to two decimal places?

Tags: php, magento

I was having trouble displaying some prices on my website in currency format (2 decimal places). Instead the values were being displayed at 4 decimal places.

Someone edited my original question and made it look terrible which made this post get negative rep!! :(.

Anyways, the answer is described below. Basically insert a function to my php variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you could use the code below:

```
$numberformatted = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks man,

I used as follows:

$MOQ_Unit_Price_formatted = number_format($MOQ_Unit_Price, 2, '.', '');
                     $BPQ_Unit_Price_formatted = number_format($BPQ_Unit_Price, 2, '.', '');